# I am having problem with my code for CS50 Python course guessing game

Tags: python, cs50

I am trying to write a program that address the requirement from CS50 Python Guessing game:

- Prompts the user for a level, �. If the user does not input a positive integer, the program should prompt again.
- Randomly generates an integer between 1 and �, inclusive, using the `random` module.
- Prompts the user to guess that integer. If the guess is not a positive integer, the program should prompt the user again.

  - If the guess is smaller than that integer, the program should output `Too small!` and prompt the user again.
  - If the guess is larger than that integer, the program should output `Too large!` and prompt the user again.
  - If the guess is the same as that integer, the program should output `Just right!` and exit.

The issue is I am passing all of the checks but I am unable pass one of the check regardless of how I try to fix my code

Here is my code

```
import random

def main():
    n_level = prompt_input('Level: ')
    game_generate(n_level)

def prompt_input(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            i = int(input(prompt))
            if i > 0:
                return i
        except ValueError:
            pass

def game_generate(n):
    result = random.randint(1,n)
    while True:
        try:
            guess = int(input('Guess: '))
            if guess > result and guess <= n:
                print('Too large!')
            elif guess < result and guess >= 1:
                print('Too small!')
            elif guess == result:
                print('Just right!')
                break
        except ValueError:
            continue

main()
```

Comment: I know a fix  _but I don't know why_! It has to do with `pytest` (which is covered in the next section). Change the `break` in the `while` loop to `exit()` and it passes.

Comment: Ok, exit() seems to fix the problem. Thanks @DinorCoderSaurus. I believe Check50 is looking for a specific program exit signal that only exit() provided while break does not.

Comment: It can also be fixed by adding `if __name__ == '__main__':` before the call to `main()` (and leaving `break` as is). Again, it has to do with `pytest`, but IDK why.